# Swift variable observers not called before super.init called

Tags: swift, observers, didset

Okay so I was reading up on how willSet/didSet are used in swift and I came across a note on apples swift docs that just doesn't make any sense to me and I hope someone can explain. Here's the note:

> The willSet and didSet observers of superclass properties are called
>   when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass
>   initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is
>   setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been
>   called.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

What confuses me is that they point out that the observers on superclass A properties in a subclass B aren't called before the super.init call by B to A.

```
class A {
    var p: Bool

    init() {
        p = false
    }
}

class B: A {

    override var p: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("didSet p")
        }
    }

    override init() {
        p = true // Compiler error
        super.init()
    }
}
```

However the property is never even accessible in that time from either A nor B, so who's gonna call the observers anyway? Attempting to read/write the property will even result in a compiler error so it's never even possible to do it by mistake in Swift. Am I missing something or is this just a misleading note that points out the wrong thing?

Comment: The difference is that `p` is actually defined in the superclass, so it must not be accessed until after `super.init()` has been called.  If `p` was only defined in the subclass, then you would be expected to set it before the call to `super.init()`.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are talking about following scenario:

```
class A {
    var p: Bool {
        didSet {
            print(">>> didSet p to \(p)")
        }
    }

    init() {
        p = false // here didSet won't be called
    }
}

class B: A {

    override init() {
        // here you could set B's properties, but not those inherited, only after super.init()
        super.init()
        p = true // here didSet will be called
    }
}

B()
```

It will print following:

```
>>> didSet p to true
```

While to you it might seems natural, the documentation has to explicitly document this behavior.

Comment: Yes I realize that they are talking about this scenario but my point is that the note is badly written and takes attention away from the issue. My question was not whether this was the issue, rather that what they say in their note is impossible to begin with.

Comment: @user614273 you are right. I think they use it as an "insurance" to mention every scenario - so while logically impossible, they are just saying that.. I guess there might be people that not realize that, would want to do it, and then would be surprised when it would not work. So this way Apple wants to make sure it won't be reported as bug. But that's just my assumption :)

Comment: I will assume that this is the case, but you know, better safe than sorry so I thought I’d better ask:) I’ve accepted your answer as correct.